# amd64 Go is giving zetasql error C++ source files not allowed when not using cgo or SWIG: bind.cc

Tags: go

Getting a build warning from zeta sql when building Big query emulator with Goccy

imports github.com/goccy/go-zetasql/internal/ccall/go-zetasql/parser/parser: C++ source files not allowed when not using cgo or SWIG: bind.cc